# HTML and Javascript Login Page (Special Characters)

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, character

I'm trying to create a login page that doesn't allow for special characters in the username.

I have done some work and have the basic outline, but I keep getting an error in line 35 (`else` part of the code). Can anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    < -- Login Page -- >
    <head>
        <meta name="login" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function checkSpecial(){
                var x = document.special.uname.value;

                //document.getElementById("pwd").innerHTML;

                //if (true){alert("getting the username "+ x);}

                regExp=/[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_@*]/; 
                if(rexExp.test(x)) {
                    { alert("Succesfull Login") }

                    else {
                        alert("Error: Invalid Username. Username may not inlcude ANY special characters.")
                    }

                    return;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <br>
    <br>
    <body>
        <form name="special" onsubmit="return checkSpecial()">
            Username: <input id="username" type="text" name="uname"/> <br>
            Password: <input id="pwd" type="password" name="pword"/> <br>

            <input type="Submit" id="login" name="Login"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which line is line 35? What is the error message?

Comment: It is the else part of the special function and it was giving me a syntax error. However that is fixed, and now I keep getting back "Regexp is not defined" Any help would help would appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` statement has too many brackets.

Try this:

```
function checkSpecial() {
 var x = document.special.uname.value;
 regExp=/[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_@*]/; 
 if(rexExp.test(x)) {
  alert("Succesfull Login");
 } else {
  alert("Error: Invalid Username. Username may not inlcude ANY special characters.");
 }
 return;
}
```

Also, it's good practice to include the semicolon at the end of all you statements, even if it's the last one.  When programming, you want it to be right before you try to minimize the code.  Just a tidbit from my experience. ^^

Comment: Thank you so much for thel help. I appreciate it. However, I tried the code and it keeps telling me that regExp is not defined(I am relatively new to the language so this might be a silly question). I thought I had the syntax correct. Any ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: Try wrapping the string in quotes.  Sorry I missed that.